# NSString : seems to have a a various formatting in XCode debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, nsstring

I have got NSString strings at various places in my code. When I debug and place the mouse pointer over a defined string, the debugger shows in a popup either something like :

[image]

or something like :

[image]

To summarize, I have got in the first case a direct view of my NSString (debugger displays "@xxxxxx"), and in the second case the number of bytes (debugger displays "X bytes"). I don't understand why the debugger behaviour seems to change according to the NSString...

Somebody can explain this to me ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have an answer. It seems that the debugger shows a number of bytes and not directly the string when there some special characters in the string. For example a line break "\r" at the end of the string. For example, when I have a string "US\r", the debugger shows "3 bytes" (whereas there only 2 visible letters on a NSLog which will give "US"). If I have the string "US", the debugger will display "US" directly. Take care to the fact that NSString with special characters like "\r" may induced bugs ; for example on predicates NSPredicate.